# k-fold cross validation model selection method

Tags: machine-learning, mapreduce, ensemble-learning

I want to know about how we select model from k-fold cross validation method. In k-fold cross validation we can get k models and an accuracy score using the average of k models' accuracies. Can you please provide a method to get the final best model from cross validation?

Answer (score 0):

K-fold cross validation is for comparing the performance of two models not for building models. Say, we desingned two 2 seq2seq generative models with different structures and our dataset is small, and we want to choose one model. We can follow the k-fold cross-validation method and get an average score for each model and choose the superior one with the higher score.

We don't need to choose a model from the k models, but we can ensemble the k modles into one by utilizing bagging(one of the three Ensemble methods). For more information please refer to this blog: [Bagging and Random Forest Ensemble Algorithms for Machine Learning](https://machinelearningmastery.com/bagging-and-random-forest-ensemble-algorithms-for-machine-learning/).

Reference:
1. https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/52277/103153
2. https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/19053/103153